# Highcharts csv data series starting with a null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I am trying to represent csv data with highcharts. I can not use a csv data that starts with a null value. How can I use a csv data where series starts with a null value. Though it works fine with 'empty' or '0' but I specifically need this to works with null or NA
please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabbishakir/Ltdupscf/)

My csv looks like this

```
Year,Annual mean,5 year mean
1880,-0.31,null
1881,-0.22,-0.25
1882,-0.28,-0.29
1883,-0.3,-0.29
1884,-0.33,-0.3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this [how-to-input-null-into-highcharts-and-then-ignore-it-in-line-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777441/how-to-input-null-into-highcharts-and-then-ignore-it-in-line-graph)

Comment: You should be able to parse your data using data.parsed: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltdupscf/5/

Comment: Thanks. data.parsed worked like a charm.